# Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split a string based on regular expression to identify a number

e.g.

```
TAX ID - CNPJ+22.111.539/0003-58, CONTACT NAME
```

from this text i want `22.111.539/0003-58`  so i have used the regex `[\r\n +:,#]`.

This is working fine for me

but i also have a text e.g.

```
CNPJ:02886427000164-CEP:04794-000**
```

from which i want `02886427000164`

so how to split the text having -CEP in it..
so that the regex split should work for both the text

Comment: Your question really doesn't have enough information to answer well, as is frequently the case with regex questions. Examples (especially just 1-2) are not enough information to write a good regex. We need to understand the underlying rules. For example, how do **you** know that the `04794` part of the second text isn't interesting? What makes the `-CEP` worth ignoring but not the `-58`? Could it also be `-ABC` or `-123`? All of these and more are likely necessary details to craft the correct regex for the use case.

Comment: Hi Joachim,

I have a set of strings and from that i have to identify these string which are usually in numeric value but these values can also have some special characters.. as i said in my first example i can get that particular string with my existing regex... but as in my second example it has -CEP added to the string   its not able to split it properly.. to be specific i want to split anything added after my string and hypen e.g 123456-2323-ABC  so here i want only 123456-2323

Comment: Again, I ask for precision: you said you "want to split anything added after my string and hypen", so by those rules you **also** want to split of `-2323`. You assume that I somehow know that "anything" doesn't include numbers or that "my string" is some numbers and/or dashes combined. Regex need precision and if your requirements are not precise, then they can't just "magic" a solution up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text1 = "TAX ID - CNPJ+22.111.539/0003-58, CONTACT NAME";
String text2 = "CNPJ:02886427000164-CEP:04794-000**";

String regex = "[\r\n +:,#-]+(?=(?:(?!CEP).)*$)";

String[] parts1 = text1.split(regex);
String[] parts2 = text2.split(regex);

System.out.println(parts1[1]); // Output: 22.111.539/0003-58
System.out.println(parts2[0]); // Output: 02886427000164
```

Using the following regex

```
[\r\n +:,#-]+(?=(?:(?!CEP).)*$)
```

we get two result, If we take second one then its your desire string

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require splitting the data, and you are simply looking for those values, you can use the following.

```
CNPJ(?:\+(.+),|:(.+?)-)
```

You can use the following method to get the number from the `String` value.

```java
String cnpj(String string) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CNPJ(?:\\+(.+),|:(.+?)-)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1) != null) return matcher.group(1);
        else if (matcher.group(2) != null) return matcher.group(2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Output, given the `String` values you provided.

```
22.111.539/0003-58
02886427000164
```

If the pattern requires more conformity, for whatever reason, you can use the following.

```
(\d\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d\d)|(\d{14})
```